# Template a shared_ptr argument

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, visual-studio-2012, c++98

I get a compiler error for this code:

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

struct Name
{
};
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Name> NamePtr;

struct Foo
{
    NamePtr name;
};
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Foo> FooPtr;

template<class T>
void setName(T item, NamePtr name = boost::make_shared<Name>() )
{
    item->name = name;  
}

int main()
{
    FooPtr foo = boost::make_shared<Foo>();
    setName(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

as follows:

```
    main.cpp: error C2780: 'boost::shared_ptr<X> boost::make_shared(A1 &&,A2 &&,A3 &&,A4 &&,A5 &&,A6 &&,A7 &&,A8 &&,A9 &&)' : expects 9 arguments - 0 provided
1>          c:\users\ebargri\desktop\boost_1_49_0\boost\smart_ptr\make_shared.hpp(590) : see declaration of 'boost::make_shared'
1>main.cpp: error C2780: 'boost::shared_ptr<X> boost::make_shared(A1 &&,A2 &&,A3 &&,A4 &&,A5 &&,A6 &&,A7 &&,A8 &&)' : expects 8 arguments - 0 provided
1>          c:\users\ebargri\desktop\boost_1_49_0\boost\smart_ptr\make_shared.hpp(534) : see declaration of 'boost::make_shared'
1>main.cpp: error C2780: 'boost::shared_ptr<X> boost::make_shared(A1 &&,A2 &&,A3 &&,A4 &&,A5 &&,A6 &&,A7 &&)' : expects 7 arguments - 0 provided
1>          c:\users\ebargri\desktop\boost_1_49_0\boost\smart_ptr\make_shared.hpp(480) : see declaration of 'boost::make_shared'
1>main.cpp: error C2780: 'boost::shared_ptr<X> boost::make_shared(A1 &&,A2 &&,A3 &&,A4 &&,A5 &&,A6 &&)' : expects 6 arguments - 0 provided
1>          c:\users\ebargri\desktop\boost_1_49_0\boost\smart_ptr\make_shared.hpp(428) : see declaration of 'boost::make_shared'
1>main.cpp: error C2780: 'boost::shared_ptr<X> boost::make_shared(A1 &&,A2 &&,A3 &&,A4 &&,A5 &&)' : expects 5 arguments - 0 provided
1>          c:\users\ebargri\desktop\boost_1_49_0\boost\smart_ptr\make_shared.hpp(378) : see declaration of 'boost::make_shared'
1>main.cpp: error C2780: 'boost::shared_ptr<X> boost::make_shared(A1 &&,A2 &&,A3 &&,A4 &&)' : expects 4 arguments - 0 provided
1>          c:\users\ebargri\desktop\boost_1_49_0\boost\smart_ptr\make_shared.hpp(330) : see declaration of 'boost::make_shared'
1>main.cpp: error C2780: 'boost::shared_ptr<X> boost::make_shared(A1 &&,A2 &&,A3 &&)' : expects 3 arguments - 0 provided
1>          c:\users\ebargri\desktop\boost_1_49_0\boost\smart_ptr\make_shared.hpp(284) : see declaration of 'boost::make_shared'
1>main.cpp: error C2780: 'boost::shared_ptr<X> boost::make_shared(A1 &&,A2 &&)' : expects 2 arguments - 0 provided
1>          c:\users\ebargri\desktop\boost_1_49_0\boost\smart_ptr\make_shared.hpp(240) : see declaration of 'boost::make_shared'
1>main.cpp: error C2780: 'boost::shared_ptr<X> boost::make_shared(A1 &&)' : expects 1 arguments - 0 provided
1>          c:\users\ebargri\desktop\boost_1_49_0\boost\smart_ptr\make_shared.hpp(198) : see declaration of 'boost::make_shared'
1>main.cpp: error C2783: 'boost::shared_ptr<X> boost::make_shared(void)' : could not deduce template argument for 'T'
1>          c:\users\ebargri\desktop\boost_1_49_0\boost\smart_ptr\make_shared.hpp(121) : see declaration of 'boost::make_shared'
```

What am I doing wrong?

If I replace the templated function with this, the code compiles fine:

```
void setName(FooPtr item, NamePtr name = boost::make_shared<Name>())
{
    item->name = name;  
}
```

It will also compile if I replace it with this:

```
template<class T>
void setName(T item)
{
}
```

And it will also compile if I pass in the second argument as follows:

```
FooPtr foo = boost::make_shared<Foo>();
NamePtr name = boost::make_shared<Name>();
setName(foo, name);
```

This doesn't compile either:

```
setName<FooPtr>(foo);
```

**UPDATE**:

Here's another example:

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp> 
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp> 

template<class T> 
void f(T item, boost::shared_ptr<int> name = boost::make_shared<int>()) 
{ 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    f(0); 
}
```

Comment: shouldn't your class have a public constructor?

Comment: @stijn structs are classes with default public constructors

Comment: I know that, yet boost doesn't seem how to construct Name here? Or I'm completely misinterpreting the error messages..

Comment: @stijn Giving default public constructors to all three classes makes no difference.

Comment: you're right, just tested this using std instead of boost and funnily enough msvc tells _'make_shared' : is not a member of '`global namespace''_

Comment: Does it work with `setName(foo)` replaced by `setName<FooPtr>(foo)` (it should, since it's effectively the same as non-template function with `FooPtr` arg)? It seems like compiler fails to infer some types.

Comment: This compiles for me, which compiler are you using?

Comment: @Salgar I'm using VS 2012

Comment: Reproduced in MSVC10 in a more trivial form: #include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

template<class T>
void f(T item, boost::shared_ptr<int> name = boost::make_shared<int>())
{
}

int main()
{
  f(0);
}

Comment: @Igor R. Added above, thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [std::make\_shared as a default argument does not compile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788765/stdmake-shared-as-a-default-argument-does-not-compile)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a VS bug. Demo:

```
namespace foo {
  template <typename T> class A {};
  template<typename T> A<T> mk_A() { return A<T>(); } 
}

template<class T> 
void f(T item, foo::A<int> x = foo::mk_A<int>()) { } // triggers the bug

using foo::mk_A;
template<class T> 
void g(T item, foo::A<int> x = mk_A<int>()) { } // does not trigger the bug


int main () {
  f(0); g(0);
}
```